# Physics of implosions - Lost submarine in South Atlantic waters

Tags: acoustics

Days ago, an argentine submarine dissapeared in waters of South Atlantic Ocean: the "ARA SAN JUAN".

There is an article from Mr. Bruce Rule which can be seen here:
https://thenewstalkers.com/community/discussion/36424/death-of-a-submarine

In it, we can read the following:

"The frequency of the collapse event signal (bubble-pulse) was about 4.4 Hz."

Can somebody from the community explain what this bubble-pulse is and how it works, how this value of 4.4 Hz is obtained. And in general, how implosions work.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when a submarine with an intact hull sinks, it eventually reaches a depth where the surrounding water pressure is sufficient to collapse or "implode" its hull. when this happens, the surrounding water rushes inwards as the hull crumples in upon itself. when the hull is completely crushed, the surrounding water keeps rushing inwards because of its inertia and it then bounces back and reverses its direction briefly. In so doing it leaves a zone of negative pressure behind in which a cloud of cavitation bubbles bursts into existence. the water flow then reverses itself and flows inwards again to neutralize the negative pressure and the cavitation bubbles vanish. this process generates an acoustic signal called a bubble pulse.

If a submarine has its hull torn open while at the surface, it fills with water and sinks- and does not undergo catastrophic collapse at its so-called "crush depth", and generates no bubble pulse signal. analysis of the acoustic signature of a sinking submarine hence allows investigators to determine probable cause.

Comment: I had read that the crush is totally catastrophic and shreds everything inside instantly: given 4.4 Hz and a 25 ft beam/draft--that's about 160 mph crush speed, with 2000-3000 tons of water participating: Painless.

Comment: evidence from the sinkings of both the Scorpion and the Thresher support your view. the part which is not painless is hanging on inside the sub in the dark as it sinks lower and lower, listening to the hull begin to give way.

Comment: I'd like to be careful not to dehumanize a tragedy like this... but additional information on the very interesting topic of acoustic cavitation can be found in this freely available document [_Louisnard and Jonzalez-Garcia 2010 'Acoustic Cavitation'_](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441974716-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1023847-p174029780)

Comment: I have several friends who served on US subs and I too wish not to dehumanize what it means for a sub to sink. as an engineer and physics enthusiast, I have a natural curiosity about things like this, especially as it relates to issues of design and management, and I try not to minimize the tragedies...

Comment: @ D. Halyn Betchkal I het the message "This page does not exist"